# "Stackoverflow Profile View" gadget doesn't seem to get added to my iGoogle page

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I added the "Stackoverflow Profile View" gadget to my iGoogle page, but it doesn't work.

I see

> Information is temporarily unavailable

inside an empty gadget.

I have deleted all my gadgets and re-added "Stackoverflow Profile View" gadget, and still get the same error.

**EDIT:**

Ah nuts! Stack Overflow has added JavaScript to de-frame itself. So, this gadget will no longer work.

Comment: What gadget is this?

Comment: @Ether i think it is named as StackOverflow profile gadget... Please search for it..

Comment: "Please search for it" -- are you kidding? Do you call the Microsoft help desk saying "This program I use has an error. I think it's called Photoshop. Please search for it and then help me."?

Comment: Now that iGoogle is on its way out, this is not only off-topic, but also too localized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consult the place that you downloaded the Stackoverflow Profile View gadget. If it was on Meta, you might want to post a comment/answer to the author's question introducing the widget.

As far as I know, the creators of Stackoverflow do not publish offical widgets, gadgets, or any other 3rd party application, as they are focused enough as it is on the actual development of the site.